# Add error in to pdo_error.ctp

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, cakephp-2.5

I want to add some errors in to `pdo_error.ctp`. What I exactly want to do? I have a form where I can insert values in to MySQL database, if I leave `text` or `varchar` input empty then its inserting in to database, but if I leave `INT` input empty, then I got error. I want error message even if `text/varchar` input is empty.

My database structure:
[image]

What I got if I leave `INT` input empty:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Maja' cannot be null

SQL Query: INSERT INTO `kontaktid`.`kontaktids` (`Eesnimi`, `Perenimi`, `Maakond`, `Linn`, `Tanav`, `Maja`, `Telefon`, `lisanumbrid`) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, '') 

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\pdo_error.ctp
```

pdo_error.ctp file

```
<h2><?php echo __d('cake_dev', 'Database Error'); ?></h2>
<p class="alert alert-error">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong><?php echo __d('cake_dev', 'Error'); ?>: </strong>
        <?php echo h($error->getMessage()); ?>
</p>
<?php if (!empty($error->queryString)) : ?>
        <p class="alert alert-info">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
            <strong><?php echo __d('cake_dev', 'SQL Query'); ?>: </strong>
            <?php echo $error->queryString; ?>
        </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (!empty($error->params)) : ?>
                <strong><?php echo __d('cake_dev', 'SQL Query Params'); ?>: </strong>
                <?php echo Debugger::dump($error->params); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<p class="alert alert-info">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong><?php echo __d('cake_dev', 'Notice'); ?>: </strong>
        <?php echo __d('cake_dev', 'If you want to customize this error message, create %s', APP_DIR . DS . 'View' . DS . 'Errors' . DS . 'pdo_error.ctp'); ?>
</p>
<?php echo $this->element('exception_stack_trace'); ?>
```

What I already tried :

I added this in to `view.ctp` file

```
$Eesnimi = ($_POST['Eesnimi']);
```

And then added this in to `pdo_error.ctp` file

```
if (empty($Eesnimi)) {
    echo "Eesnimi is empty";
}
```

I really want get error, if these text inputs are empty. I can add form file too, if its necessary.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: You probably do pass the data to the query. But you can put NULL if strlen of trim (of the string) it's 0. If you do not put null you are passing an empty string, it's because of this that you haven't got an error (i think)

Comment: hmm.. Okay I can try.

Comment: How I can put this like this , if `Eesnimi` is empty then this value is NULL, but its varchar and not null

Comment: after $Eesnimi = ($_POST['Eesnimi']); , if(strlen(trim($Eesnimi)) == 0){$Eesnimi = null;} something like that?

Comment: To modify these errors is not possible?

Comment: I see only one error posted. Instead of printing the error given from db you can print what you want

Comment: I think that, this view file is not connected with pdo_error file, because its always output `Eesnimi is empty`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at data validation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html